# C# XNamespace initialization concept

Tags: c#

XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";

How this is possible ? Normally to create an instance of a particular class we need to use the New keyword or a specific static method returning the created instance.

There is a specific implementation allowing this to be possible ?
Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XNamespace class has an implicit operator defined that converts from type String to type XNamespace.

[XNamespace Implicit Conversion (String to XNamespace) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_implicit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit conversion operator defined in `System.Xml.Linq`, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_implicit(v=vs.110).aspx).